# SQL Show values from one column based on values from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following issue: SQL table that I have looks like this:

[image: sql table]

What I would like is to show value of column 2 where only values '76' and '83' are present in column 3. So, that would be only '1' because value '2' has also '84' and value '4' does not have value '76'. How would the query for this look like?

Comment: Specify the expected result table as well - formatted text here too. And show us your current query attempt. And tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Hi, I am using SQL Server 2014. I have tried with grouping but that does not give me the groups with ONLY 76 and 83.

Comment: As I've already said. Add sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) And also show us your query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Expected result would be really helpful. But this should get you going.

```
SELECT [fkGroupResourceSeatingOption..] 
FROM [YourTable] 
WHERE [fkResourcecelte..] IN ('76','83')
```

Comment: Thank you, Kumar! But the result should be '1', because I would like only values from column 2 that have '76' and '83' in column 3.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant I'm afraid, but it does do what you want.  Still trying to think of a better way!

```
declare @test table
(
pkG int,
fkG int,
fkR int
)
insert into @test VALUES
(1,1,76),
(2,1,83),
(5,3,76),
(6,3,83),
(7,3,84),
(8,4,83),
(9,4,84)

SELECT DISTINCT fkG FROM
@test  
WHERE fkG NOT IN 
(SELECT fKG FROM @test 
WHERE fkR <> 76 and fkR <> 83) 
AND fKG IN
(SELECT fKG FROM @test 
WHERE fkR = 76) 
AND fKG IN
(SELECT fKG FROM @test 
WHERE fkR = 83)
```